# RSS and PHP merging

Tags: php, rss

I've got the following code which is causes me some issues

```
<?PHP
 include("../panel/config.php");
 #// Timetable Clearup Variabls
$yesterday = strtotime('yesterday');
$yesterdow = date('l',$yesterday);
$order = "SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE day = '$yesterdow' ORDER BY time";
$result = mysql_query($order);
$yesterdayd = date('F jS, Y', time()-86400);

    //SET XML HEADER
    header('Content-type: text/xml');

    //CONSTRUCT RSS FEED HEADERS
    $output = '<rss version="2.0">';
    $output .= '<channel>';
    $output .= "<title>Timetable - {$yesterdayd} </title>";
    $output .= '<description>Timetable.</description>';
        $output .= '<link>www.site.com</link>';
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //BODY OF RSS FEED
   $output .= '<item>';
     $output .= "<description>" . htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . " " . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</description>";
   $output .= '</item> ';
 }
    //CLOSE RSS FEED
   $output .= '</channel>';
   $output .= '</rss>';

    //SEND COMPLETE RSS FEED TO BROWSER
$filename = "timetable.xml";

                if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w')) {
            echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
            exit;
            }

            // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
            if (fwrite($handle, $output) === FALSE) {
            echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
            exit;
            }

            if (fwrite($handle, $total) === FALSE) {
            echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
            exit;
            }

            echo "Success, wrote {$content}{$total} to file ($filename)";

            fclose($handle);


?>
```

This results in a .xml rss feed being created however everything is in it's own individual `<item></item>` and `<description></description>` which causes trouble. Is there a way to wrap `<item><discussion>`ALL OF THE CONTENT`</discussion></item>`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify your loop to this:

```
$output .= '<item><description>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  //BODY OF RSS FEED
  $output .= htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . " " . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "<br/>";
}
$output .= '</description></item> ';
```

Essentially, you don't want the `item` and `description` tags being output with every item, so they belong outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, this edit works but is there a way to add a line break <br /> when there is a new row of data?